How to sort by order of values in a select statement same as values "in" clause for postgresql
I want to use a SELECT query with an IN clause, as well as Order by value same as IN clause
Query:
select * 
from table 
where column_xyz IN ('124','225','111') // Here values must be in single quotes in query


Output needs to be fetched : 124,225,111

Tried query :
  select * 
    from table 
    where column_xyz IN ('124','225','111') order by field(column_xyz,'124','225','111')

In mysql we have option called  'FIELD' but for postgres I am unable to work with 'FIELD' i.e it didn't work

select t.* 
from the_table t
inner join
 unnest(array[124,225,111]::integer[]) with ordinality as a(v, o)
 on column_xyz = v
order by o;


Better use array[124, 225, 111] (for ints, or array['124', '225', '111'] otherwise), no reason for string_to_array. Otherwise this is exactly how I'd do it, +1!

@Bergi  I tried your answer but getting error  'operator does not exist: character varying = integer'

@user_1234 Not my answer, but you need to use ::varchar[] instead of ::integer[] (and appropriate values) if you have a varchar column. Though probably you should change the column type if you're actually storing integers in there? Or maybe just provide a better example with non-numeric values in your question.

@Bergi Well, string_to_array makes sense for a parameterized query, string_to_array(?, ',') .

@Stefanov.sm Postgres supports passing arrays as parameters, not only strings - ?::varchar[] should work.

As you pointed out, Postgres does not directly support any function like MySQL's FIELD() function.  The canonical way to do this in ANSI SQL uses a CASE expression in the ORDER BY clause:
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
WHERE xyz IN ('124', '225', '111')
ORDER BY CASE xyz WHEN '124' THEN 1 WHEN '225' THEN 2 WHEN '111' THEN 3 END;

In case you actually need to sort many more than 3 possible xyz values, then you should maintain a table which maps each xyz value to its sort order:
table: xyz_ord

xyz | ord
124 | 1
225 | 2
111 | 3

Then, join to this table and use the ord column to sort your original query:
SELECT t1.* 
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN xyz_ord t2
    ON t2.xyz = t1.xyz
WHERE t1.xyz IN ('124', '225', '111')
ORDER BY t2.ord;


for demo purpose I have posted only 3 values inside IN clause but I have more values so using CASE for all those values are not possible

@user_1234 Why not? How is it possible to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to field in mysql?

@Bergi The OP's concern is that an arbitrarily large CASE expression in the ORDER BY clause will become unwieldy.  The best solution here is to maintain the orderings in a proper bona-fide table.

@TimBiegeleisen when we use inner join it is fetching multiple records however  actual records should be get 3 only bcoz I am passing only 3 values inside IN clause and in table also each one have single record but using inner join duplicating the same record

If you dynamically create IN clause in application, you can directly point desired order.
select * 
from test
inner join (values('124',1),('225',2),('111',3))t(xyz,ord) on column_xyz=xyz
order by ord

Expanded output



id
column_xyz
n
ord




1
124
124
1


3
225
225
2


2
111
111
3




Your application should put the array into the placeholder and that's it. Don't create a dynamic IN or VALUES: too much work, no functional need for and in many cases it creates a risk of SQL injection.
